# h2o, different stopping metric leads to different optimal for hyperparameters

Tags: machine-learning, r, random-forest, optimization, hyperparameter

I want to choose the "optimal" hyperparameters for gbm. So I run the following code using the `h2o` package

```
# create hyperparameter grid
hyper_params = list(ntrees = c(10,20,50,100,200,500),
                    max_depth = c(5,10,20,30),
                    min_rows = c(5,10,20,30),
                    learn_rate = c(0.01,0.05,0.08,0.1),
                    balance_classes=c(T,F))

# random subset of hyperparameters
search_criteria = list(strategy = "RandomDiscrete", max_models = 192, seed = 42,
                       stopping_rounds = 15, stopping_tolerance = 1e-3, stopping_metric = "mean_per_class_error")

# run grid
gbm.grid <- h2o.grid("gbm", grid_id = "gbm.grid", x = names(td.train.h2o)[!names(td.train.h2o)%like%"s_sd_segment"], y = "s_sd_segment", 
                     seed = 42, distribution = "multinomial",
                     training_frame = td.train.hyper.h2o, nfolds = 3,
                     hyper_params = hyper_params, search_criteria = search_criteria)

# sort results
gbm.sorted.grid <- h2o.getGrid(grid_id = "gbm.grid", sort_by = "mean_per_class_error", decreasing=FALSE)

hyperparameters_gbm <- as.data.table(gbm.sorted.grid@summary_table)
```

This gives as optimal combination for the hyperparameters

```
learn_rate  max_depth   min_rows    ntrees
0.08    10  5   200
```

Then I am trying to do the same but with different `stopping_metric`. So in the above i use `mean_per_class_error`, and in the following i use `logloss`, so i run the following code:

```
# create hyperparameter grid
hyper_params = list(ntrees = c(10,20,50,100,200,500),
                    max_depth = c(5,10,20,30),
                    min_rows = c(5,10,20,30),
                    learn_rate = c(0.01,0.05,0.08,0.1),
                    balance_classes=c(T,F))

# random subset of hyperparameters
search_criteria = list(strategy = "RandomDiscrete", max_models = 192, seed = 42,
                       stopping_rounds = 15, stopping_tolerance = 1e-3, stopping_metric = "logloss")

# run grid
gbm.grid <- h2o.grid("gbm", grid_id = "gbm.grid", x = names(td.train.h2o)[!names(td.train.h2o)%like%"s_sd_segment"], y = "s_sd_segment", 
                     seed = 42, distribution = "multinomial",
                     training_frame = td.train.hyper.h2o, nfolds = 3,
                     hyper_params = hyper_params, search_criteria = search_criteria)

# sort results
gbm.sorted.grid <- h2o.getGrid(grid_id = "gbm.grid", sort_by = "logloss", decreasing=FALSE)

hyperparameters_gbm <- as.data.table(gbm.sorted.grid@summary_table)
```

which gives as optimal combination for hyperparameters

```
learn_rate  max_depth   min_rows    ntrees
0.1 20  5   500
```

I know that i use as argument `strategy = "RandomDiscrete"`, but still for instance the optimal combination for gbm using `stopping_metric = "mean_per_class_error"` is the "50th optimal combination" for the gbm using `stopping_metric = "logloss"`, and the "2nd optimal combination" for gbm using `stopping_metric = "logloss"`, is the "14th optimal combination" for gbm using 
`stopping_metric = "mean_per_class_error"`

Why could that happen ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are using different metrics to determine how well you are doing, that means it's not weird that different metrics find different hyperparameter settings that work better. Second of all, some hyperparameters might not matter for the problem you are solving, which means all the signal you are getting from those hyperparameters is noise. Third of all, most of the machine learning algorithms are stochastic, meaning there is randomness involved in training them and sometimes in evaluating them, this means even starting the same grid or random search could lead to different hyperparameters. That said the probability of that is only high if the real performances are close to each other.